# Filling date form

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to fill this date form:

HTML:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(["/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input"]/option[@type="01-12-2020"]).click()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Python-3.8.0/Ispot JP.py", line 26
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(["/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input"]/option[@type="01-12-2020"]).click()
                                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You have several `"`'s within each other - i.e. inside the string itself, and the string is delimited by `"`. Either prepend the quotes with a backslash - `\"`  - or use single quotes on the outer level - `'`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [@MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh) in the comments above, your function expects a string.

You currently don't have your string in quotation marks, which throws an error. Also as Mats mentioned, if you put your xpath in quotation marks, be sure to escape any quotation marks in your xpath-string like this `\"` or use single quotes on the outer level

Also I'm pretty sure your xpath shouldn't start with brackets - but you should check that yourself. An easy way to get the xpath for an element, is in the inspector of your browser. In firefox for example you can right click the element, go to 'inspect element (Q)' and right click it in the source-tree. In the context menu under copy you can then select copy xpath, which should return the valid xpath of that element

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input/option[@type=\"01-12-2020\"]").click()
```

or

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input/option[@type="01-12-2020"]').click()
```